# Why is Dev Tools bar empty?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, srware-iron

I'm using Chrome-compatible [SRWare Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php) 5.0.381 on XP, and was checking out what Chrome has to offer to developers, EG inspecting the contents of the DOM of a currently-loaded web page.
But when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, the bar is totally empty:

[image: screenshot of empty toolbar]

Does someone why this is? Do I need an add-on? Are there other Chrome-compatible tools I should know about?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you’ve found a bug in that fork of Chromium. The inspector works just fine with Google.fr in the [latest Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?extra=devchannel) and [Chromium builds](http://build.chromium.org/buildbot/snapshots/chromium-rel-xp/54473/). Why don’t you use one of these browsers.

Comment: I prefer not to use Chrome because of the privacy issues. I'll try Chromium. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the reason of that is some problem in DevTools JS code.

It is a chance that problem will be solved by chrome restart.
Such kind of problems can happen when chrome is upgrading at background.

The other reason of that can be some changes which you made in DevTools.js.
Of cause if you have done some changes :)

You can troubleshoot such problem by another instance of DevTools.
As example you can try to load DevTools.html page into Safari, open WebInspector for it and check console messages.

Comment: I've misread that you use Chrome.

In case of Iron it is a chance that Iron was compiled without DevTools support in native code.